# Fit form items to its display width

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0qoNgVqBZt?layout=horizontal)

I’d like to fit form items to their display width.

Each form is nested within `li` element.

And, I could manage to fit `li`  elements to display width.

but their child elements (which are form elements ) do not stretch to the `li`  element.

I understand form elements (eg. `input`, `textarea`)  are inline so that they should fit as wide as their parent.

Would you help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `w-full` for child elements of the `li` and remove `m-3`. Instead of `m-3` in childs, give `p-3` in `li` elements

```html
<!doctype html>                                                                                               
<html class="h-full">                                                                                         
<head>                                                                                                      
  <meta charset="UTF-8">                                                                                  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                                      
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>                                                 
</head>   
<form class="bg-blue-100" action="/events" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="Wn6NqXmIH7TeOeRE4XU28HGJfRwsUwJq1ykMHqza1v6aiKmoQCgKMi_j0TG5SLwMXGTeyudhcjk4UY2aeI_i_w" autocomplete="off" />
  <ul class="flex flex-wrap">
    <li class="w-screen p-3">
      <input placeholder="Event Name" class="w-full rounded border-transparent text-gray-700" type="text" name="event[name]" id="event_name" />
    </li>
    <li class="w-screen p-3 bg-red-500">
      <input value="2022-04-23" class="w-full rounded border-transparent text-gray-700" type="date" name="event[event_date]" id="event_event_date" />
    </li>
    <li class="w-screen p-3 bg-red-50">
      <textarea placeholder="Memo" class="w-full rounded border-transparent text-gray-700" name="event[memo]" id="event_memo"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="w-screen">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit" class="ml-auto block" data-disable-with="Submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to nest the elements inside `li` but whatever you see
the only thing you need to add to the child element is `w-full`

have a look:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/pEY3BsH3qv

Comment: your suggestion doesn't seem to work because there're no paddings and mergins on the right side of forms...

Comment: @qo_op yes, maybe because you didn't mention it, you only asked for the elements to take the full width, anyway good you found an answer